# Ongoing CORS issues (Vue 3 / Axios + ASP.NET Core Web API (backend))

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I am perplexed. I have partial success when running my .net core server and then loading the vue proj in the same file as the other. When I have begun testing what's wrong with the axios/fetch requests I'm making, the test project is failing in other ways.

I have my cors policy wide open in .NET in `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ToDoApp.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", policy => 
       {
           policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5173");
       });    
});

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
 options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The relevant portion of my controller (I'm trying the most basic `GetAll` type request at this point):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ToDoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public ToDoController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ToDo>>> GetToDos()
    {
        return Ok(await _context.ToDos.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

My `launchsettings.json`:

```
{
 "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
 "iisSettings": {
 "windowsAuthentication": false,
 "anonymousAuthentication": true,
 "iisExpress": {
 "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40665",
 "sslPort": 44316
    }
  },
 "profiles": {
 "ToDoApp": {
 "commandName": "Project",
 "dotnetRunMessages": true,
 "launchBrowser": true,
 "launchUrl": "swagger",
 "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7029;http://localhost:5096",
 "environmentVariables": {
 "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
 "IIS Express": {
 "commandName": "IISExpress",
 "launchBrowser": true,
 "launchUrl": "swagger",
 "environmentVariables": {
 "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

App.vue (I've condensed just about everything I'm trying to do in this file):

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import {ref} from 'vue'

const API_URL = "http://localhost:5096/api/todo"

export default {
 setup () {
 const apiData = ref('')
 
 const loadApi = async () => {
 try {
 const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
 apiData.value = response.data.apiData
      } catch (e) {
 console.error(e);
      }
    }
 loadApi();
 return apiData;
  }
}
</script>

<template>
 <header>
 </header>

 <main>
 <p class="p-quote">{{ apiData }}</p>
 </main>
</template>

<style scoped>
#app {
 font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.p-quote {
 color: white;
}
</style>
```

Alas, I always see some console error along the lines of the attached photos. HELP!
[image: a typical error, be it fetch or axios]
[image: 200 response on the red/error transmission]
[image: 301 response here...perhaps the root of all of the issues]

I have tried a lot, some of which is outlined in the original post body. I have recalibrated the Vue syntax (I am very new to the framework), I have combed through the network and console responses. I have connected through both a browser, postman, and a different vue proj, this one actually within the overall proj folder with my backend .net files.

I both added and removed the forward slash at the end of the urls.

Comment: What if you include like this `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5096/api/todo");`?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron A Web origin doesn't contain a path.

Comment: Means what? Its  not a  path, full URL.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5096");` would make sense, but `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5096/api/todo");` makes no sense because `http://localhost:5096/api/todo` is not a valid [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin).

Answer (score 0):

For testing at local, you should allow any domain access resource.
Replace this code with the one below

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", policy => 
       {
           policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5173");
       });    
});
```

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", policy => 
       {
           policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .WithOrigins("*");
       });    
});
```

Comment: A method that will at least let me console.log the response: builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(s=> true).AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("*");
    });
});

Comment: This was a blend of reddit and DinhTX's suggestion. I didn't realize how much fine tuning the CORS policy can require. Valuable lesson. And you can use "[EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]" attributes in the controller on an endpoint-by-endpoint basis. Seeing what's the issue with the Vue export awaits! Thank you!